# Solution for apps that don't scale on HiDPI displays

Tags: 17.04, display-resolution, 4k-monitor, hdpi

My laptop has a 15-inch 4k display. Almost everything works perfectly, but some applications don't scale and are too small to use. Some examples: Hipchat, Ardour, Steam, Gimp, etc.

Is there a way for me to solve this? I've seen to use `xrandr` to set DPI before running the app, but that seems to have no effect (or I'm doing it wrong.)

If I could fix this one problem I'd have everything working perfectly.

Also, I'm using Gnome, but the issue was the same in Unity.

Answer (score 13):

As olivierb2 pointed out there is no simple, global way to accomplish this. However, I did find a way to perform window scaling on a per-app basis that works very well, but not for all applications.

I found a script called [run_scaled](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled) that acts as a front end for xpra, which is like screen for X. It basically sets up a second X server scaled to whatever you choose, runs your app, and then forwards it to your primary display. In order to use it you need to install some deps:

```
sudo apt-get install xpra winswitch xvfb
```

Install it:

```
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaueraal/run_scaled/master/run_scaled" > ~/.local/bin/run_scaled
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/run_scaled
```

And after that [on a new shell](https://www.xpra.org/trac/ticket/1698) you run your app like so:

```
run_scaled someapp
```

If you test your app(s) that you need scaled and it works you can make it a little more user friendly by copying the script to somewhere in your path and editing the .desktop file for your app so it will launch scaled from your DE.

The downside is that this doesn't work with every app. It seemed to work fine for all of the FOSS apps I tried, but non-free apps like Steam and HipChat didn't work. Not a perfect solution, but it can help in a pinch.

Comment: Is there any way to always run some apps scaled?

Comment: @Victor Yes. The way I do it is to (1) write a one-line command that invokes the application using `run_scaled` the way I want and save this to a shell script (say, in `$HOME/bin/.MyAppScript.sh`), (2) create a [Desktop file](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) (which is a 10-ish line text file, not difficult to learn how to make) that executes the shell script in #1 and save this DEsktop file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`, and finally (3) launch from, place in your dock favorites, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As @Adam Drew recommends, use `run_scaled`.

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install:

```
sudo apt install xvfb xpra xrandr
```

Then download `run_scaled` script from [this zip](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled/archive/master.zip) and put it in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Then to launch your program, do **for example**

```
run_scaled ./soapui.sh
```

It works very well on Java Swing apps that don't scale naturally.

Answer (score 3):

For individual applications that use Qt5, you just need to edit the `.desktop` file. I will give you an example with a snap application like OpenSCAD.

1. Go to `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.
2. Find your `.desktop` application, in this case `openscad_openscad.desktop`.
3. Edit the file (with `sudo`) and find the line `Exec=...`. In our case the line is:

   ```
   Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/openscad_openscad.desktop /snap/bin/openscad %f
   ```

   and you have to change it to:

   ```
   Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/openscad_openscad.desktop QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5 /snap/bin/openscad %f
   ```

   Note that `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2.5` was added. Adjust the value of `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` to one you're comfortable with.
4. Save your file.
5. Restart your application.

Answer (score 2):

As @Riki137 said, you could also use `run_scaled` on 20.04, but `xrandr` is no longer needed. `x11-xserver-utils` replaced it

So all you need to do on 20.04 is:

```
sudo apt -y install xvfb xpra
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaueraal/run_scaled/master/run_scaled
```

put it under `/usr/local/bin` and you are good to go

Comment: Just tested this in 22.04 with `kdiff3` and `x2goclient` – works well.

Comment: @Melebius likewise works well for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and the `projectlibre` app installed with snap.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Unity nor GNOME supports HiDPI very well yet, but this will improve soon. You can improve useability by just increasing the size of the fonts using to [unity-tweak-tool](http://apt://unity-tweak-tool). Open **Fonts** in the **Appearance** section, and adjust the Text scaling factor.

Firefox don't take any notice of Unity tweak settings, so you have to configure it manually. Just open it, type **about:config** in the URL and set parameter **layout.css.devPixelsPerPx** to the same value that you defined in Fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The HiDPI scaling in both Unity and GNOME seems pretty good actually. Almost every app I use is working fine: Firefox, Chrome, Visual Studio Code, Ryhtmbox, GNOME Shell, all of the built in apps, Evolution, etc. Almost everything is scaling perfectly. So, I don't need a global solution like editing font sizes. I need some way to deal with apps that aren't respecting those settings. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess there is no global solution yet, and you may need to configure each apps (if possible) to adapt their scaling.