# OpenSCAD has unreadably tiny interface text on UHD display

Tags: gnome, display, fonts, interface

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome Desktop on a UHD laptop display. My system's fonts have generally been tweaked using the font scaling in Gnome Tweak Tools, but this has had no effect on OpenSCAD which has an unreadably small interface font.

How can I change the font size without effectively lowering the screen resolution (e.g., without using Settings>Devices>Display>Scale>200%).

Comment: Does `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2` or `xrandr --dpi 144`fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the `run-scaled` script 
mentioned here: [Solution for apps that don't scale on HiDPI displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960019/solution-for-apps-that-dont-scale-on-hidpi-displays).