# Two screens with different resolutions

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Recently I bought the Dell XPS 15 7590 and I wanted to hook up a second screen. But as it turns out the external monitor, which is connected through HDMI, is only Full HD (1920x1080).

And so when Ubuntu boots up and I log in the screen on my laptop the scaling is perfectly fine (what a surprise), but the second screen is **MUCH** bigger than it has to be.

[image: Screenshot of the scaling issue]

How is it possible to run two different screens with different resolutions, but with the right scaling?

I have heard about [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse) for Windows, but haven't found any alternative for Linux. It would be nice if somebody could tell me a similar software.

Comment: You can find an answer in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/960019/solution-for-apps-that-dont-scale-on-hidpi-displays?newreg=9c2046d892e24ab5a75ef1c0a746bbab

Answer (score 5):

You can scale screens independently from built in settings:

settings -> devices -> screen display

Click on the monitor you want to change then choose appropriate scale.

If you need more customization you could use xrandr (built in configuration utility to the RandR (Resize and Rotate) X Window System extension). it does affect the resolution though.

use `xrandr | grep 'connected'` to find active displays, identify which monitor you wish to change. The part you're after is the characters on a new line before the first space.

for me: `eDP-1`

<strike>Then you can use `xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.5x0.5`</strike>

Edit: Then you can use `xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 2x2` to zoom out (0.5x0.5 zooms in)

For more indepth use of xrandr scaling without the negative side effects you could try reading [this blog](https://blog.summercat.com/configuring-mixed-dpi-monitors-with-xrandr.html). Looks legit, but not tested.

Comment: I'll try that in the next days and will give you feedback to your answer. Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: `settings -> devices -> screen display` doesn't work (either on Ubuntu 22.04, neither Wayland nor X), the size selection is located in the device-specific part of the UI but will actually apply to all devices. I couldn't find any way to have different zoom on different monitors on Wayland. On X, `xrandr` seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I needed to not only change the scale, but also enable "Fractional Scaling" in Settings > Displays to solve this problem.  My first monitor was 3840X2400, and my second monitor was 1920X1080.  I set the scale of the first to 200%, the second to 100%, and enabled fractional scaling.

After I enabled the Fractional Scaling I had to move the screens around in the GUI to get them to be side by side (they were separated).  Now I have both monitors at different scales.

[image]

Comment: This prevents my mouse from hitting the "wall" created by the difference otherwise. Thanks so much for mentioning the "Fractal Scaling". Cheers!

Comment: things were fine with 2 screens and worked as described. But when using a 3rd screen on my display port it is zoomed in and causes usability issues Any ideas here? I am going to check if the display port and hdmi port can be scaled like the built in screen and the hdmi and add new comment or edit this one.

Comment: So after poking at it a bit I find my display port and hdmi use same scaling, It uses what ever is set for the hdmi  for the display port. It is not clear if this is a hardware of software issue. FYI, I have no mirrored screens.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently discovered [Cursr](https://cursr.app), it works on windows, mac and linux. It seems to be in early stage/new but so far I didn't have issues with it, works fine. I tried LittleBigMouse couple times over few years before on windows but just couldn't get it to work properly

Comment: Just tried it on Linux, works perfect, thanks !