# 3rd video output(display port) wont fractal scaling independently of the hdmi output

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

https://askubuntu.com/a/1400572/112263

I found this question/answer that suggested using the fractal scaling option to get screens to act as if they were same size. I want this so there is no "screen wall" on the built in display of my laptop a gaze16 more information about my laptop can be found here:
https://tech-docs.system76.com/models/gaze16/README.html

To be clear I have the 3050 graphics card and I am using the nvidia-driver-530 running **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)**

Basically if I am using 2 screens being the hdmi output and the built in display I can use the fractal scaling without issue. Though when using the display port with 2 or 3 displays and enabling fractal scaling it seems like the display port uses the setting that is suppose to be for the hdmi port.

A screenshot of how i want it shows all 3 displays as the same size but I have to go off screen view to take this screenshot:
[image: A screenshot of how i want it shows all 3 displays as the same size but I have to go off screen view to take this screenshot]

---

This picture is of what the right side screen (display port) actually shows on the monitor:
[image: This picture is of what the right side screen (display port) actually shows on the monitor]

---

I was thinking xrandr verbose output might while fractal scaling is on might help someone help me so here that output.

```
    $ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 11520 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  79955573
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: bilinear
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0006af90af00000000
        081e0104a5221378033e859156599128
        1f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101348a80a0703864406c30
        350058c110000018dc3780a070383e40
        6c30350058c110000018000000fd003c
        90a5a522010a202020202020000000fe
        004231353648414e30382e34200a00b5
    vrr_capable: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    panel orientation: Normal 
        supported: Normal, Upside Down, Left Side Up, Right Side Up
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 308 
        supported: 308
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x45) 353.800MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2028 end 2076 total 2080 skew    0 clock 170.10KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1180           clock 144.15Hz
  1920x1080 (0x46) 333.111MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock 160.15KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock 144.15Hz
  1920x1080 (0x47) 143.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2028 end 2076 total 2080 skew    0 clock  68.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1142           clock  60.20Hz
  1680x1050 (0x48) 286.453MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock 155.68KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock 144.15Hz
  1400x1050 (0x49) 293.222MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock 155.97KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock 144.15Hz
  1600x900 (0x4a) 234.928MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock 133.48KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock 144.15Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4b) 259.383MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock 153.66KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock 144.15Hz
  1400x900 (0x4c) 208.232MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock 133.48KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock 144.15Hz
  1280x960 (0x4d) 259.468MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock 144.15KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock 144.15Hz
  1368x768 (0x4e) 174.005MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock 113.88KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock 144.15Hz
  1280x800 (0x4f) 170.834MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock 118.63KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock 144.15Hz
  1152x864 (0x50) 207.574MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock 129.73KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock 144.15Hz
  1280x720 (0x51) 153.813MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock 106.81KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock 144.15Hz
  1024x768 (0x52) 156.151MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock 116.18KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock 144.15Hz
  1024x768i (0x53) 74.430MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1024 start 1032 end 1208 total 1264 skew    0 clock  58.88KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  776 total  817           clock 144.15Hz
  960x720 (0x54) 281.091MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock 216.22KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock 144.15Hz
  928x696 (0x55) 262.010MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock 207.29KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock 144.15Hz
  896x672 (0x56) 245.955MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock 200.94KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock 144.15Hz
  1024x576 (0x57) 101.208MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  85.48KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock 144.15Hz
  960x600 (0x58) 184.995MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock 177.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock 144.15Hz
  832x624 (0x59) 110.762MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  96.15KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock 144.15Hz
  960x540 (0x5a) 89.764MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  80.15KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock 144.15Hz
  800x600 (0x5b) 92.255MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  90.09KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock 144.15Hz
  840x525 (0x5c) 143.226MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock 155.68KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock 144.15Hz
  864x486 (0x5d) 73.804MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  72.07KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock 144.15Hz
  700x525 (0x5e) 146.611MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock 155.97KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock 144.15Hz
  800x450 (0x5f) 117.464MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock 133.48KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock 144.15Hz
  640x512 (0x60) 129.691MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock 153.66KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock 144.15Hz
  700x450 (0x61) 104.116MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock 133.48KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock 144.15Hz
  640x480 (0x62) 60.542MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  75.68KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock 144.15Hz
  720x405 (0x63) 53.150MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  60.40KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock 144.15Hz
  720x400 (0x64) 60.175MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  756 end  828 total  936 skew    0 clock  64.29KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  446           clock 144.15Hz
  684x384 (0x65) 87.002MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock 113.88KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock 144.15Hz
  640x400 (0x66) 53.369MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  64.15KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  445           clock 144.15Hz
  576x432 (0x67) 103.787MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  672 total  800 skew    0 clock 129.73KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  450           clock 144.15Hz
  640x360 (0x68) 43.129MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  53.91KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock 144.15Hz
  640x350 (0x69) 53.369MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  64.15KHz
        v: height  350 start  382 end  385 total  445           clock 144.15Hz
  512x384 (0x6a) 78.075MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock 116.18KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock 144.15Hz
  512x384i (0x6b) 37.169MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  516 end  604 total  632 skew    0 clock  58.81KHz
        v: height  384 start  384 end  388 total  408           clock 144.15Hz
  512x288 (0x6c) 50.519MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  85.34KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock 144.15Hz
  416x312 (0x6d) 55.297MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   416 start  432 end  464 total  576 skew    0 clock  96.00KHz
        v: height  312 start  312 end  314 total  333           clock 144.15Hz
  480x270 (0x6e) 44.882MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  80.15KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock 144.15Hz
  400x300 (0x6f) 46.053MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  89.95KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock 144.15Hz
  432x243 (0x70) 36.902MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  72.07KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock 144.15Hz
  320x240 (0x71) 30.213MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  75.53KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock 144.15Hz
  360x202 (0x72) 26.511MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  60.25KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock 144.14Hz
  360x200 (0x73) 30.087MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  378 end  414 total  468 skew    0 clock  64.29KHz
        v: height  200 start  200 end  202 total  223           clock 144.14Hz
  320x200 (0x74) 26.624MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  336 end  368 total  416 skew    0 clock  64.00KHz
        v: height  200 start  200 end  202 total  222           clock 144.14Hz
  320x180 (0x75) 21.564MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  53.91KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock 144.14Hz
  320x175 (0x76) 26.624MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  336 end  368 total  416 skew    0 clock  64.00KHz
        v: height  175 start  191 end  192 total  222           clock 144.14Hz
HDMI-1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (0x7f) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 16mm x 9mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  79955573
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff00410c000000000000
        001e0103800000780a2fcda354459724
        114647210800950081809040b3000101
        01010101010108e80030f2705a80b058
        8a0010090000001e023a801871382d40
        582c450010090000001e000000fc0050
        68696c697073204654560a20000000fd
        00173f0f873c000a20202020202001ac
        0203477050615d5f6662641003202204
        02050607012909070715075057070083
        0100006d030c00100038442000600103
        0467d85dc401788003e20059e305c000
        e20f3fe3060f018c0ad08a20e02d1010
        3e9600100900000018011d803e73382d
        407e2c458010090000001e0000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000db
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 317 
        supported: 317
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  3840x2160 (0x77) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock 135.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  60.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x78) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock 135.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  60.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x79) 593.407MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  4096x2160 (0x7a) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x7b) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x7c) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  4096x2160 (0x7d) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  3840x2160 (0x7e) 593.407MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  3840x2160 (0x7f) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x80) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x81) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x82) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  1920x1080 (0x83) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x84) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0x85) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x86) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  30.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x87) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  27.00KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  24.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x88) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x89) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  29.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x8a) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
  1680x1050 (0x8b) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1400x1050 (0x8c) 101.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  64.74KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1080           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x8d) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x8e) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x720 (0x8f) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x90) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x91) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x92) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x480 (0x93) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x94) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x480i (0x95) 13.514MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.75KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480i (0x96) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.73KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x97) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x98) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
DVI-I-5-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x2ae
    Timestamp:  21613
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      4
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 37 
        supported: 37
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DVI-I-4-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x28d
    Timestamp:  21613
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 37 
        supported: 37
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DVI-I-3-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x26c
    Timestamp:  21613
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      6
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 37 
        supported: 37
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DVI-I-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x24b
    Timestamp:  21613
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      7
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 37 
        supported: 37
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DP-1-0 connected 3840x2160+7680+0 (0x83) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    Identifier: 0x225
    Timestamp:  79955374
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       8
    CRTCs:      8 9 10 11
    Transform:  2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: bilinear
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    PRIME Synchronization:      supported: ?, ?
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010ac7ea0554c3841
        22160104a5301b78e6ee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a54b00714f8180d1c001010101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e000000ff00313734
        523732384e41384c550a000000fc0044
        454c4c205032323132480a20000000fd
        00384c1e5311000a20202020202000a5
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x83) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x226) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x8d) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1152x864 (0x227) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x228) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x91) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x229) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x92) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x22a) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x98) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x22b
    Timestamp:  79955374
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      8 9 10 11
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x83) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x8d) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x91) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x92) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x98) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? Please use edit and add this info to the question not as a comment.

Comment: @David I added it and I also changed the tags to reflect the OS. thanks for any help or guidance offered.