# The font size of Java-based application for 4K screen

Tags: 18.04, java, display, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

My laptop is `hp spectre x360 13` and my OS is `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`. I want to use a Java-based application called `paraprof`[(here)](http://www.paratools.com/). Sorry, I don't use Java so I put part of its description below (don't know whether it helps):

```
ParaProf requires Oracle / Sun's Java 1.5 Runtime Environment for basic functionality.
Java JOGL (included) is required for 3d visualization and image export. Additionally,
OpenGL is required for 3d visualization.
```

The problem is when I launch it the font size is too small to read:
[image: paraprof]

I think this is a scaling problem on high DPI display? The built-in display of my laptop is `3840 * 2160`, and in `setting - screen display` section I set the `Scale` option as `300%`.

I encounter a similar scaling problem before, the font size of `spotify` is also really small. I solved this one by adding `alias spotify="/snap/bin/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=3.5"` in my `bashrc` file. I wonder if there is similar solution to this one.

I see some people suggest to use `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.0` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1100193/1053942), but I am not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an answer there: [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/960041/1053942)

So this one is to use a script acts as the front end of `xpra`. It can perform a scaling to the specific applicaiton you required.

```
// install some dependencies 
sudo apt-get install xpra winswitch xvfb

// install it
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaueraal/run_scaled/master/run_scaled" > ~/.local/bin/run_scaled

chmod +x ~/.local/bin/run_scaled

// then you can run your app
run_scaled someapp
```

Although this one works fine, I wonther if there is other way to achieve the scaling problem.