# Some installed programs are very small size on ubuntu

Tags: installed-programs

Some programs installed on ubuntu appear with small size it hasnt setings for modify your size. I try modify de resolution on display but affect only to the desktop of ubuntu but the program appear with the same charateristics of size. For Example I installed Global Protect and i cant read funtionalities and settings of this program for the problem of size

Comment: Add information on your Ubuntu version, graphics card and current resolution to your question: use "edit". Issue is that these applications do not support high res displays. If you reduce the resolution of the desktop, these applications will appear bigger.

Comment: Related: [Solution for apps that don't scale on HiDPI displays](https://askubuntu.com/q/960019/250300)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution for apps that don't scale on HiDPI displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960019/solution-for-apps-that-dont-scale-on-hidpi-displays)